# onbeforeunload confirmation screen customization

Tags: javascript, onbeforeunload, confirm

Is it possible to create a custom confirmation box for the onbeforeunload event in a browser? I tried but then I get 2 confirmation boxes (one from me which is nothing more than return confirm... and then the standard one from the browser).

At the moment my code looks like:

```
var inputChanged = false;

$(window).load(function() {
    window.onbeforeunload = navigateAway;
    $(':input').bind('change', function() { inputChanged = true; });
});

function navigateAway(){
    if(inputChanged){
        return 'Are you sure you want to navigate away?';
    }
}
```

I'm using jQuery for this.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

```
window.onbeforeunload = function (e) {
  var message = "Your confirmation message goes here.",
  e = e || window.event;
  // For IE and Firefox
  if (e) {
    e.returnValue = message;
  }

  // For Safari
  return message;
};
```

Please note: Most browsers put this message after some other text. You do not have complete control of the content of the confirmation dialog.

Comment: It's indeed, unfortunately, not possible to override this screen.

Answer (score 3):

No, you can't avoid the standard one from the browser. All you can do is inject some custom text into it; if you use the following event handler (registered the prototype lib way):

```
Event.observe(window, "beforeunload", function(event) {
    if (showMyBeforeUnloadConfirmation)
        event.returnValue = "foo bar baz";
});
```

(and `showMyBeforeUnloadConfirmation` is true) you'll get the browser's standard confirmation with the following text:

> Are you sure you want to navigate away from this page?
>
> foo bar baz
>
> Press OK to continue, or Cancel to stay on the current page.
>
> [   OK   ] [ Cancel ]

Answer (score 0):

I faced the same problem, I was able to get its own dialog box with my message, but the problems I faced were:

1. It was giving message on all navigations and I wanted it only for close click.
2. With my own confirmation message if user selects "Cancel", it still shows the browser's default dialog box.

Following is the solutions code I found, which I wrote on my Master page.

```
function closeMe(evt) {
    if (typeof evt == 'undefined') {
        evt = window.event;
    }
    if (evt && evt.clientX >= (window.event.screenX - 150) && evt.clientY >= -150 && evt.clientY <= 0) {
        return "Do you want to log out of your current session?";
    }
}

window.onbeforeunload = closeMe;
```