# How do I open a form on page exit

Tags: javascript, dom-events

I'm now dealing with a client request to open a form when the user leave the page.
Can that be done?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems to be impossible to create my own form and override onbeforeunload or anything else. I guess blocking it is the right thing though..

What we did is to pop a form and use the regular onbeforeunload. if the user wants to go - he will. But if he stays - he will get the questionnaire.

---

You can see the issue here too: [onbeforeunload confirmation screen customization](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1335727/onbeforeunload-confirmation-screen-custumization)

Answer (score 0):

I think you are looking for

[onbeforeunload](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/window.onbeforeunload) event

> An event that fires before the unload
>   event when the page is unloaded.

Comment: While this event is well known, it will fire an event but the page will be closed and the form will not be loaded.