# how to stop page redirect

Tags: javascript, jquery

I need to stop all the page redirection through javascript.

I have some script which will redirect the page to some other location.
How can I stop all the page redirection on my page through jquery or javascript.

Answer (score 80):

You can stop the redirect by doing the following.

```
<script language="JavaScript" type="text/javascript">
    //<![CDATA[
        window.onbeforeunload = function(){
            return 'Are you sure you want to leave?';
        };
    //]]>
</script>
```

Not sure if all browsers support this but that should do the trick.

Comment: It's ingenious in it's simplicity. On a sidenote - it's the only method that appears to stop malicious scripts from redirecting using `window.location.replace()` or `window.location.href="virus"` type of things. Helped me with debugging, so thanks a lot.

Comment: Is it possible to get the URL that it is redirecting to using this method?

Answer (score 2):

If I'm understanding you correctly, you need to stop users navigating away from the page?

If so, Marcos Placona's answer is one part of it - although all what you actually need is:

```
$("a").click(function(e) { e.preventDefault(); });
```

You also don't want people to hit F5 I'm guessing? Well that's harder. Preventing defaults on key press, cross-browser is horrible. But a couple of codes that work in some browser are below here:

```
function disableF5() {  // IE
    document.onkeydown = function() {
        if (window.event && window.event.keyCode == 116) { // Capture and remap F5
            window.event.keyCode = 505;
        }
        if (window.event && window.event.keyCode == 505) { // New action for F5
        return false; // Must return false or the browser will refresh anyway
        }
    }
}
function disableF5v2() { // FIREFOX
    $(this).keypress(function(e) {
        if (e.keyCode == 116) {
            e.preventDefault();
    return false;
        }
    });
}
```

However, the cross-browser issue can partly be solved with -

```
window.onbeforeunload = function(e) {
    var message = "Your confirmation message goes here.", e = e || window.event;
    // For IE and Firefox 
if (e) {
    e.returnValue = message;
}
// For Safari
    return message;
};
```

Hope that all helps anyway. The last bit of code is from another question on this site [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1335727/onbeforeunload-confirmation-screen-custumization).
Rob

Comment: Seriously, someone needs to down vote Rahul's answer. He might as well have said "you can't have text on a page, full-stop".

Answer (score 2):

Are you trying to stop an iframe breaker? Something like:

```
<script language="JavaScript" type="text/javascript">
<!--
function breakout_of_frame()
{
  if (top.location != location) {
    top.location.href = document.location.href ;
  }
}
-->
</script>
```

If so, you can not.

Comment: HTML5 supports `sandboxed` iframes. "prevent the content to navigate its top-level browsing context". http://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_iframe_sandbox.asp

Answer (score 1):

If it's only redirects through link clicks, in jQuery you can do this:

```
$(".someClass a").unbind('click');
```

if it's an existing page redirect, you'll need to give us some more information about what kind of redirect this is, so we can help further.

Hope this helps you

Comment: that would assume all anchors are bound by jQuery. To be sure one should use $(a).unbind('click'), $(a).die(), $(a).removeAttr('onClick')

Comment: In jQuery >= 1.7, you should use `.off()` instead of `.unbind()`

Answer (score -5):

AFAIK this won't be possible, since page redirection can occur in many ways. He can click on an anchor tag, can submit a form with different action, set window.location to another page on button click and invoke server code to redirection.

And you won't be able to detect many of these.