# Javascript Change class does not behave properly

Tags: javascript

I've used a javascript to change the image on a menu list item (from css class)when its clicked.
Its supposed to change from "menu_grey" to "menu_red". It does happen but its momentarily switched back to the same class. This is what I have in HTML:

```
     <li %WELCOME_ACTIVE%><a id = "menuClicked" class='menuHome' href='%AuthProgram%'>%lang("lang_customer_framework_home")%</a>

<script>

document.getElementById("menuClicked").onclick=function() {

var className = document.getElementById("menuClicked").className

document.getElementById("menuClicked").className = "menuClicked"


};
</script>

</li>
```

As this is an alteration of the design in a pre-developed website and the layout of the menu is defined in CSS, i dont want to make a new menu and design as i would then risk to destroy rest of the design. The CSS class looks like this:

```
#menu li a.menuHome
{
  background: url('../graphics/SevenCustomer/ikoner/hjem_gra.jpg') no-repeat top center;
  display: block;
  padding-top: 44px;
}
```

And for menuClicked:

```
#menu li a.menuClicked
{
  background: url('../graphics/SevenCustomer/ikoner/HJEM_rod.jpg') no-repeat top center;
  display: block;
  padding-top: 44px;
}
```

So the question is: 
How can I make the image stay "red" after clicking home ?

Suggestions are appreciated :)

Answer (score 0):

The page navigates away, you would need to set it on the serverside or on the page that loads. The next page has no clue that you added a class to it. It does not care since it is a brand new page.

Comment: Do you need the page to reload? If not cancel the click event.

Comment: Its actually the same page I'm coming back to. 
I.e all this code is in framework.html.
Clicking on home would just get it back to home.

Im working on serverside now.

Comment: When home is clicked its supposed to reload, but also the image is supposed to change to red and stay on red as long as home is active. 
When another menu item is clicked, home goes back to grey and the other icon is supposed to become red..

Comment: It the page is supposed to reload than you are going to have to have the serverside set the class OR you are going to have to use cookies/localstorage to remember state.

Comment: Do you have any simple example of how to achieve this ?

Answer (score 0):

Just stop the event from firing when someone clicks on the link. There are several ways to do this, here's a few suggestions:

[how to stop page redirect](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2635370/how-to-stop-page-redirect)