# Jquery intercepting anchor click change of page

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am wanting to intercept anchor clicks and show a prompt if text has changed and not been submitted in a form using zebra-dialog. For any other form of page leaving I use the built in browser unload dialog.

Here is the code I have so far, the dialog shows, but no matter which option you click you end up staying on the page.

```
$("body").on("mousedown",'a', function(e) {

    if(inputhaschanged) {
        return $.Zebra_Dialog("You haven't submitted your comment. Do you wish to leave?", {'type':'question','title':'','buttons':  [
                {caption: 'No', callback: function() {  }},
                {caption: 'Yes', callback: function() { return true; }}]
        });
    }

});
```

Comment: looks like the `Zebra_Dialog` is an async method.. so you can't do it like this... you need to manually do a page redirect on the `Yes` handler

Comment: Thanks @ArunPJohny, do you mean something like this in the Yes callback?
window.location.href = $(this).attr("href");

Answer (score 0):

One solution for this is you disable default behavior of all link on your page and then check for modification. Also you need to call event `window.onbeforeunload` to prevent other navigation method.
Reference: [how to stop page redirect](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2635370/how-to-stop-page-redirect)
[How do you prevent a webpage from navigating away in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/821011/how-do-you-prevent-javascript-page-from-navigating-away)