# Stop page redirection using javascript without warning or asking

Tags: javascript, redirect

[This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2635370/how-to-stop-page-redirect) tells how to stop redirection:

```
<script language="JavaScript" type="text/javascript">
    //<![CDATA[
        window.onbeforeunload = function(){
            return 'Are you sure you want to leave?';
        };
    //]]>
</script>
```

This codes works, but asks an user whether to stay on the page or redirect. Can the redirect be stopped without any type of alert or asking?

Comment: Are you sure that it will be user friendly? Visitor would never be able to leave your page

Comment: That did not work on my mind.

Answer (score 5):

No, it cannot. If that were allowed, a malicious page could permanently prevent someone from leaving it. Therefore, the user must be allowed to decide.

If you are leaving from an event handler though, you can usually `return false` to stop it from happening.