# Prevent button to page redirect in html

Tags: javascript, php, html

I have a few buttons and a submit button. (Making simple) My idea is to receive the value of the clicked button using a php and display it **only when submit**. Here I face a problem that button click itself redirects to the page and displays the value (means it is not waiting for the submit button to press). I followed a javascript provided [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2635370/how-to-stop-page-redirect). But didn’t work. Any method to achieve this?

```
<form action="calculate.php" method="POST">

<button type="" name="btn" style="background-color:#7F77AE" value="Alf">x1</button>
<button type="" name="btn" style="background-color:#7F77AE" value="ABI">y1</button>
<button type="" name="btn" style="background-color:#7F77AE" value="APE">z1</button>

<input type="submit" value="Submit">
```

php part is as simple as,

```
 $button = $_POST['btn']; 
 echo $button;
```

Comment: You need a submit type `<button type="submit"` plus all buttons need unique name attributes in order for this to work. Then use `isset()` based on the button pressed.

Comment: @Fred-ii-, but setting button type to submit shows the same issue of page redirection before clicking actual submit button. OR did i misunderstood your suggestion..!!

Answer (score 0):

Define the plain button's type as "button"

```
<form action="calculate.php" method="POST">

<button type="button" name="btn" style="background-color:#7F77AE" value="Alf">x1</button>
<button type="button" name="btn" style="background-color:#7F77AE" value="ABI">y1</button>
<button type="button" name="btn" style="background-color:#7F77AE" value="APE">z1</button>

<input type="submit" value="Submit">
```

EDIT: If you absolutely *need* to use buttons here you can do something like this:

```
<script>
function select(val){
    document.getElementById("btnValueStore").value = val;
}
</script>

<form action="calculate.php" method="POST">
<button type="button" style="background-color:#7F77AE" onClick="select('Alf')">x1</button>
<button type="button" style="background-color:#7F77AE" onClick="select('ABI')">y1</button>
<button type="button" style="background-color:#7F77AE" onClick="select('APE')">z1</button>
<input type="hidden" value="" name="btn" id="btnValueStore">
<input type="submit" value="Submit">
</form>
```

First you define a hidden input to hold the value of the last pressed button.

The select function changes the value of the hidden input field to whatever value you pass it.

For each of your buttons set the "onClick" property to call the select function with the corresponding button's value.

Note: This particular implementation allows only 1 button to have been "selected" (the last one you clicked) - for the ability to "select" more than one button you will need multiple hidden input fields.

Comment: If I use <button type="button" , then echo $button is empty @Abovestand

Comment: Sounds like checboxes might be more appropriate here. Buttons are for triggering events, not storing input. If you absolutely need buttons then you'll need some hidden inputs whose value you manipulate on the onClick events of the buttons.

Comment: Thanks @Abovestand, but could you tell me a little more as I didnt get it completely.

Comment: Can users "select" (click) multiple buttons? Or are you only interested in the last clicked button?

Comment: only the last clicked button value need to be stored @Abovestand