# Detect if page will redirect and block it javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, redirect

I have a website where I can modify clientside behaviour but can't control ther server respond.

I am trying to detect if one of thoses pages will respond to the client with 200 (inside session) or will redirect them (outside). Is it possible to test the status respond with ajax from a different page? I googled for a solution but didn't find any.

If this is not possible, then I would like a user to visit the page and if it will try to redirect the user, I want some javascript that will detect the redicrection, stop it and instead redirect it myself on some other page instead of leaving it for the server. In this case, how to detect redirection on page in clientside?

Comment: please share code what you have tried so far

Comment: Redirection happens from browser, not via javascript code. I don't think you would have any control over this from your app.

Comment: Try this hack though https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2635370/how-to-stop-page-redirect