# Why is my JavaScript search function redirecting to "http://localhost:8090/?"?

Tags: javascript, html, redirect, server, client

I am creating a webserver that, at the moment, is being hosted on http://localhost:8090. It consists of an HTML file, a server.js and a client.js file. I have managed to set up communication between the client and the server perfectly for my needs. My problem lies in that when I click on my search button, everything executes fine except for some reason it will redirect the page to 'http://localhost:8090/?' when I need it to stay on 'http://localhost:8090/' for it to dynamically update the HTML.

I have searched extensively and found nothing that is similar to my problem. I found this one question https://stackoverflow.com/a/2647601/5264986 but this will bring up a dialog box every time the page wants to go to a different address which is not what I need. I have gone through all my code and there is no redirect or href that points to this location. I have narrowed it down to this function in client.js:

```
function search(){

    var search = document.getElementById('txt_field').value; 

    fetch('/search', {
        headers: {text: search}
    })
        .then(response => response.json())
        .then(function(data) {

            // CODE HERE TO DYNAMICALLY UPDATE HTML

        })
        .catch(error => console.error(error));

}
```

and in my server all that happens for this is:

```
app.get('/search', function(req, res){

    var text = req.get('text');
    var url = 'https://api.spotify.com/v1/search?q=name:'+text+'&type=track';
    var content = httpGet(url);
    res.send(content);

});
```

where httpGet is an xmlhttprequest.

## Edit

This is the html for the search button:

```html
<button id="send_btn" class="btn btn-outline-secondary my-2 my-sm-0"><img src="./images/search.png" width="30"></button>
```

and in client.js this is what triggers it:

```
document.getElementById('send_btn').onclick = search;
```

### End of edit

It sends content fine back to the client, but for some reason it then redirects to :8090/? which reloads the html file and overwriting the dynamic html.
Any pointers in the right direction would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: You've not shared the HTML, so we don't have a full picture of what's happening. However, it looks very much like your search button submits a form via GET and you've not prevented the default behaviour?

Comment: Note `httpGet` is asynchronous

Comment: Sorey @RobinZigmond I will add it now

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add a `preventDefault` to your event handler. I assume that the function `search` is getting called when you click on the button. If so then you need to pass in the event like below:

```js
function search(evt){
  evt.preventDefault(); // <--
  var search = document.getElementById('txt_field').value; 

  fetch('/search', {
    headers: {text: search}
  })
    .then(response => response.json())
    .then(function(data) {

      // CODE HERE TO DYNAMICALLY UPDATE HTML

     })
     .catch(error => console.error(error));
}
```

`preventDefault` will tell the browser to not do the default action of the button, which is to submit the form.

So `preventDefault` lets the browser know that you do not want it to submit the form, thus preventing the redirect from happening.

Comment: Thank you so much! The preventDefault fixed it, and yes sorry I realised I hadn't included the HTML at first but then edited the original question and added it and the search() trigger