# confirm() on window.onbeforeunload

Tags: javascript

I want to show a confirmation dialog if the user wants to leave the page with unsaved form data. What I have is:

```
window.onbeforeunload = function() {
    if (not_saved) if (confirm('Changes will not be saved')) return true;
    return false;
}
```

But no matter what the user clicks, the result is the same - the stupid hardcoded dialog box that asks them whether they want to leave the page or stay on page. What I want to ask them is whether they want to stay or leave, and if they want to stay nothing happens, if they want to leave, they leave. Is this even possible? I can see how browsers want to limit what websites can do about keeping the users on the page, but I think I've seen some websites (Google Docs I think) having nice civilized dialog boxes.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

```
window.onbeforeunload = function(e) {
    return 'Dialog text here.';
};
```

Docs:

- https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/window.onbeforeunload
- http://dev.w3.org/html5/spec-LC/history.html#unloading-documents

> **Note that in Firefox 4 and later the returned string is not displayed to the user.**
>
> If the returnValue attribute of the event object is not the empty
>   string, or if the event was canceled, then the user agent should ask
>   the user to confirm that they wish to unload the document.
>        The prompt shown by the user agent may include the string of the returnValue attribute, or some leading subset thereof. (A user agent
>   may want to truncate the string to 1024 characters for display, for
>   instance.)

Comment: This isn't changing the dialogue text for me, still same old boilerplate...

Comment: @Uzebeckatrente please notice my answer is from 2012 and please read Note in yellow box. All major browsers todayh won't change string. It was used by scam websites.

Comment: https://www.chromestatus.com/feature/5349061406228480

Answer (score 13):

Although `window.onbeforeunload` works, it's considered bad practice. It's better to use something like the following:

```
if (typeof window.addEventListener === 'undefined') {
    window.addEventListener = function(e, callback) {
        return window.attachEvent('on' + e, callback);
    }
}

window.addEventListener('beforeunload', function() {
    return 'Dialog Text Here';
});
```

First we check if `window.addEventListener` exists, which it does not in IE, else we polyfill it, and then we attach the event.

Comment: Setting the event just by setting `window.onbeforeuload` is a really bad idea as it may mess with any other events that have been set. Instead, we "listen" for the event by adding an event listener. But in Internet Explorer, `window.addEventListener` doesn't exist, so we fake it using window.attachEvent, which does exist but with a slightly different syntax.

Comment: Well that's another problem I didn't even know I had. Th... thanks.

Comment: won't change dialog text for me, any solution now? 2019?

Answer (score 1):

With jQuery, you can set the same handlers. The code may defer based on your version.

```
    function AnyFunction(e){ /**** your code *****/ };

    $(function () {
      $(window).bind('unload', function (e) { return AnyFunction(e); });
      $(window).bind('beforeunload', function (e) { return AnyFunction(e); });
    });
```

You can also change the confirm or alert [function](https://jsfiddle.net/xpvt214o/651687/) using plugins as [bootbox](http://bootboxjs.com/).