# JSF How to display the Navigation confirm popup before forwarding to other page

Tags: jsf, primefaces

I'm using Primfaces Layout component in my pages and I'm not using Redirection in navigation when user clicks on the Menu links.

i.e.,I'm **NOT** using `faces-redirect?true` and URL doesn't change when user navigates.

I want to display a Confirmation Dialog before user navigates away from current view, like

> “Are you sure you want to navigate away from this page?”

So once user clicks on the `OK` then it should forward to other page or else it should stay in same page if user clicks on `CANCEL`.

One more constraint is I want this functionality for only few selected pages not all of them.

What is the best approach to deal with this problem?

*Primefaces Version: 3.5

JSF Version: 2.1.13

All my ManagedBeans are in @ViewScoped*

Comment: When you say, you want this only for selected pages, does it mean: I want ON A SELECTION of pages, that the dialog on that pages appears. or does it mean: I only want that dialog appear, when I browse away TO selected other pages? In the first case, stick with javascript and see the article http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12132060/confirm-on-window-onbeforeunload

Comment: @L-Ray : Consider I have 4 Pages Home,Register,Feedback and Contact. I want the dialog to fire when user is in Register page and try to navigate to any other page.

Comment: If you're dealing only with the navigation provided by your links, just show a primefaces panel, which will provide a button wich acts like a link in the case of `OK`, and the `CANCEL` button will just hide the panel. I see nothing more here. Other case would be if you want to manage the time when user closes the tab, you'll need to handle page unload event as @L-Ray suggests.

Comment: @XtremeBiker: Hey thanks for reply, is there any other way to do it without touching or altering the Menu links code? may be an event which behaves like opposite of javax.faces.event.PreRenderViewEvent ?

Comment: Don't think it's possible not changing them. If you navigate to other page, you're already sending a GET request for that, there's no confirmation needed for that. You definitelly need to use your panel before that GET happens.

Comment: @XtremeBiker : Its actually a POST request, as I mentioned in question I'm NOT using `faces-redirect=true`. So I thought it might be possible.

Comment: Can you post your current code please?

Comment: Hi @KishorP, got any further with the problem described?

Comment: Hi Kishor, did you got solution?, i need the way to show dialog when user change the view, thanks

Answer (score 0):

If you want to try solving this problem from javascript-side, either go with

```
window.onbeforeunload = function(e) {
    return 'Dialog text here.';
};
```

and see the dialog independent from the link being clicked (see https://stackoverflow.com/a/12132076/1269441). or try adding

```
onclick="if (!confirm('Your dialog-text here')) {return false;}"
```

to a selection of links you would like to have the dialog shown.

Comment: Hey L-Ray.., No this method is not working.. I'm using FORWARD not REDIRECT so URL won't refresh.

Comment: The `window.onbeforeunload` works on my Firefox 26.0, so does the `onclick`-method below. The unload works independent from Forward or Redirect (at least on the upper described browser).