# Confirm user to submit a form before page closing via jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, forms, confirm

I want to get the confirmation from the user to save a form before page closing with confirm() javascript function. If user pressed **Ok** button, run save form action and if pressed **Cancel** button, then close page.

for that I write this :

```
window.onbeforeunload = function() {
    if (confirm('Are you want to save Form ?')){
        //saveActions
    }
    return 'You have unsaved changes!';
}
```

But `onbeforeunload` event for window object does not run confirm() function and jsut it's own confirmation dialog box with string that is next to **return** instruction.

How can I do that?

Comment: you can't use `confirm` or `alert` inside `onbeforeunload`. Many browsers won't even use the returned string as display. That function was so abused years ago that there is very little you can do inside it

Comment: Possible duplicate of [confirm() on window.onbeforeunload](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12132060/confirm-on-window-onbeforeunload)

Comment: Please use no pop-ups when user tries to close the tab! This is one of the worst available techniques. It's super annoying when you try to just close a tab but a popup tries to hinder you. Instead how about automatic saving through AJAX or local memory, or detecting an exit intent by checking pointer position (most users click on the x in the tab or window frame). Also keep in mind that most browsers remember what you typed in forms.

Comment: @ManasovDaniel, your suggested topic was not my problem solution

Comment: @Hubert Grzeskowiak- depending upon the application, for unsaved data I believe it is acceptable at times- coupled with autosaving to reduce the instances of this happening. Not saying just because they do it it is ok, but Facebook and Gmail are two examples that spring to mind where this happens

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is natural behavior.

`window.onbeforeunload` is restricted in operation to prevent it being exploited.

Discouraging or polling the user for opinion after the final closing action is a bad practice.

Try options like periodically saving your data, having inner "Close" button etc.