# Prevent user from going to other tab on website

Tags: javascript, asp.net, .net

I'm not sure how you can do this, but if a user on my site enters some information and selects another link or tab without saving, I would like to present a popup and allow them to cancel that action. If the action is canceled, I want to prevent the user from going to the selected link/tab.

Can you actually do this? I've thought about using onuload javascript event but I'm not sure how you could prevent the action.

This is a ASP.net site using jquery.

Comment: [onbeforeunload](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window.onbeforeunload)

Comment: @Pointy that works for the same page, what about opening on another tab?

Comment: I know of no way that a page can prevent the user from choosing (or launching) another tab. If I did, I would promptly report it as a severe denial-of-service security bug.

Comment: possible duplicate of [onbeforeunload confirmation screen customization](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1335727/onbeforeunload-confirmation-screen-customization)

Comment: By tab, I mean same site but other tab on the site. @Pointy can you prevent the user from going to another tab on same site using onbeforeunload?

Comment: @Oscar ok wait - when you say "tab", what exactly are you talking about? If it's some control *inside your own page*, then yes you can do whatever you want; disable the control, hide other tabs, threaten the user, whatever. But if you're talking about *browser* tabs, like for separate websites, then no.

Comment: Generally what you'd do for your own pages is watch for "keypress" and "paste" events in your form fields so that you can set a flag when there's typed but unsaved stuff. Then make your event handlers for other controls check for that status.  Of course there are a lot of details and interaction issues, but they completely depend on the architecture of your particular site.

Comment: @pointy thanks, I think you point me to the right track

Comment: [**Try this**](http://jsbin.com/tiheliyo/2).

Answer (score 0):

It's a rather imperfect solution, but this is as close as I could get.

Add this event handler to your page:

```
window.onblur = function() {
    var flag = confirm("Please don't leave!  Click OK if you really want to leave.  I hope you click cancel and stay with me.");
    if (flag) {
        window.onblur = undefined;
        alert("Ok you can leave now.  **sob**");
        //The user is leaving.  You can do a little cleanup here if you need to.
    }
}
```

Note: No solution in the world will prevent a user from opening another *browser*.  Or, better yet, picking up their mobile phone and browsing from there.  You can't force the user to remain focused on your app.

I strongly suggest you rethink your UX design if it really is so fragile that you can't allow the user to multitask.